# Ubuntu 12.04 on MBPro, Early 2011, options

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, macosx, macbook-pro

I have a 2.2 GHz i7, 4GB MacBook Pro 8.3, AMD Radeon HD 6750M 1024 MB, Early 2011. 
As far as I see I have two options, running Ubuntu on this hardware:

1. VMWare/Virtualbox and Ubuntu in a VM, I already ordered a 16G RAM upgrade for this.
2. Wipe OSX and go Ubuntu native, with 16G RAM, yay !

I'm kinda leaning towards option 2 as I tend to spend 90% of my time in dev VM's at work anyway. All my other machines at home, and most at work are Ubuntu/Linux as well. I have a Mac mini on standby for the odd Itunes backup/sync. If I don't have to keep OSX around, I would like to get rid of it altogether.

Ubuntu support on Mac hardware seems to be a hit and miss affair as far as I can tell. Does anyone have good success running a recent version of Ubuntu on this hardware ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see [this document](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro)

I currently run Ubuntu on my MBP. It works quite well. First I resided the OS X partition to as small as I could using Disk Utility. This took a very long time. Then I installed refit. Then booted and installed Ubuntu 12.04. I used the free space on the drive to put the Linux partition.

A few tips.

- Use BIOS mode, or it won't work.
- Don't completely remove OS X. Your going to need it. (EFI updates etc.)
- Flush your NVRAM and PMU after you install Linux. Linux doesn't use it and it helps clear some settings OS X sets that can cause issues (like keyboard light levels).

Comment: Thanks mate. I should have mentioned that I did review that doco, but my specific combo was not mentioned. Thanks for the tips, I missed the EFI update requirement.

Comment: Yeah those pages need some lovin'. It should work just fine as long as you use BIOS mode and take care of your fan situation right off.

Answer (score 1):

Keep separate Ubuntu & OS X.

OS X on a disk and Ubuntu on another.
If you have only one disk...

I don't know if it's true today but you must divide your hd area in 3 areas:

1. OS X
2. nothing (from 10 to 50 KB)....
3. Ubuntu

2-bis that *nothing* must be between the two OS because their contact blocks your machine.
I do not know why it happens...

Sorry for my english...